# Mala experiencia de usuario: Me han mandado a realizar el recorrido de bienvenida

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

**Prólogo**

Esta es una publicación asociada al [28 de Diciembre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADa_de_los_Santos_Inocentes), no pretende ser seria ni que sea tomada en cuenta realmente.

Cualquier persona (usuario) que se sienta ofendido o se sienta de alguna manera referenciado en mi publicación, no es esa mi intención y pido disculpas por anticipado.

## FUNDAMENTOS DE HECHO

Hace poco luego de realizar mi primera pregunta en el sitio (nunca había formulado preguntas en SOes, sólo había dado respuestas), un usuario que no mencionaré para no someterle al escarnio público típico de las publicaciones en Meta (creo que es uno de los objetivos de Meta ¿no?, someter a otros al escarnio público). Lo cierto es que un usuario, o tal vez "une usuarie", (no entraré en debates sobre esto), me dejó el típico comentario copia y pega de:

> `Bienvenido a ....blah blah blah, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de bienvenida, ... blah blah`

¿Cómo osa este particular usuarie en comentar de tan nefasta manera una pregunta realizada por mi? Yo, que tengo todos los récords del mundo mundial respondiendo preguntas en SOes, yo que tengo más de 10K de reputación, yo que nunca en mi vida he usado otra IA para responder que no se Ch**e**atGPT.

## PETICIÓN

Exijo a los moderadores diamantados que hagan un seguimiento de este usuarie que me ha ofendido en tal magnitud que he tenido que pedir la baja laboral por depresión profunda. He tenido que cancelar todos mis planes de cara a las celebraciones de Navidad y Año Nuevo. Temo por la estabilidad emocional de mi familia e incluso temo por mi salud mental los próximos 10 años como mínimo.

Y viendo que las peticiones **coherentes** que se reciben en Meta últimamente, no son apoyadas por la comunidad, y viendo que los mensajes o comunicados con los CM, y que se publican libremente en Meta (a pesar de ser de carácter privado), tampoco calan en la voluntad de la comunidad, a pesar de haber miles (realmente 2) usuarios que luchan por cambiar el sistema a toda costa (y a medida, claro), hago la siguiente propuesta.

## PROPUESTA

Mi propuesta para el sitio se enumera en los siguientes puntos a continuación:

**Todos los moderadores diamantados humanos deben ser removidos de sus puestos y ser sustituidos por bots de Inteligencia Artificial. (Salve IA, salvadora de la humanidad)**

Esta propuesta es una innovación en el sitio ya que eliminan el factor humano. El **factor humano es algo que hay que erradicar sólo cuando se trata de la moderación**. Ya que es nefasto, hace que se formen "camarillas", que son como sectas en SOes. Estas "camarillas" se reúnen en privado, y deciden el futuro de todos los usarios de la red. Lo sé, porque he sido víctima de sus arbitrariedades, y conozco a muches otres usueries (una gran mayoría de les usuaries registrades) que han sufrido la ignominia de la "camarilla".

**El centro de ayuda debe ser removido del sitio ya que nadie lo lee, ocupa espacio y distrae.**

Si bien esta propuesta puede ser un poco controversial, piénsenlo bien. Han habido innumerables peticiones sobre el ajustar lo que dice el centro de ayuda. Todas estas peticiones han sido rechazadas o incluso simplemente no tomadas en cuenta (¿tal vez porque afectan a toda la red y debieron hacerse en Meta en inglés?). Entonces mi propuesta es innovadora, fresca y podemos tener datos relevantes del sitio, como la cantidad de veces que dicho Centro de Ayuda es realmente visitado. Tengo los números aquí al lado mío y son abrumadores, sólo puedo decir que nadie jamás visita ese lugar, ha de ser el sitio menos visitado de toda la Internet. Entonces, y dado que mis conclusiones por sí solitas bastan, hago esta propuesta. Podríamos sustituir el Centro de Ayuda por un servicio de atención o soporte personalizado 24/7, atendido por supuesto por la IA. (Salve IA, salvadora de la humanidad).

**La publicación de preguntas / respuestas debe tener un captcha IA freindly, o no tener captcha en absoluto.**

De vez en cuando me topado el típico captcha humanista retrógrado (No soy un robot). Esto es denigrante para la IA, es absurdo en esta época de usuarios nóveles que han ganado reputación con el uso de esta herramienta tan poderosa y **acertada** (aunque lo nieguen, saben que es así). Propongo que las respuestas tengan un captcha diferente, fresco y que a la vez sea inclusivo. Sin embargo, viendo que cualquier captcha que se use puede ser considerado ofensivo por cualquier entidad susceptible, mejor no poner captcha alguno. Eso sería realmente inclusivo. Incluiría no sólo a la IA sino a los flooders y parásitos digitales que hasta ahora han sido oprimidos por este sistema despótico. (Salve IA, salvadora de la humanidad)

**El chat de SOes debe ser convertido en el soporte 24/7 del sitio.**

Muchos debates acalorados se dan en este lugar, donde hordas de usuarios pululan a diario, congestionando a veces o saturando el socket de comunicación que lo mantiene vivo. Debido a esta alta afluencia de usuarios en el chat (en promedio se conecta más del 60% de los usuarios de todo SOes en un día típico), el chat se ha convertido en el sitio idóneo para debatir temas tan importantes como: **¿Quién me votó negativo sin comentar?**, o **¿Dónde está mi punto?**, e incluso el inmortal: **Quiero mi voto castigo**. Debido a esto, el chat ha perdido su esencia principal:

> *Chat de la comunidad de Stackoverflow en español. A veces charlamos sobre temas de programación, discutimos preguntas y/o respuestas, hablamos de tecnología y otras cosas. Habla, convive, conversa, responde, pregunta, pero siempre desde el respeto.*

Y se ha convertido en el muro de lamentos, dimes y diretes y el ataque de los flags. Es por ello que propongo convertir el chat en un soporte 24/7, controlado por la IA (Salve IA, salvadora de la humanidad).

Para acceder al chat no haría falta una reputación elevada, cualquier Troll tiene el derecho de entrar, pero al ser la IA una entidad perfecta, nunca ningún Troll podría trolearle, por lo cual es arma disuasoria suficiente. Los flags se levantarían en caso de que temas no relacionados con los admitidos por la IA se discutan o tengan vida en el chat.

**Todas la preguntas y respuestas deben tener normas de cortesía incluidas**

Detesto ver cómo se degrada la humanidad, (aunque algunos le llaman cambio). Se han perdido las normas y buenas costumbres. Hay usuarios que van editando mis respuestas quitando los saludos y cortesías, y se atreven a llamarlo "ruido".

Mi propuesta es que toda pregunta o respuesta inicie con un saludo pertinente, y una pequeña introducción personal de no menos de 3 líneas. La IA se encargaría de verificar si se están cumpliendo estos parámetros (Salve IA, salvadora de la humanidad). Así, una pregunta podría verse de la siguiente forma:

> Querido lector,
>
> Es con el debido respeto y la expectante esperanza de su amable atención que me permito dirigirme a usted en esta apacible tarde. Mi nombre es El Troll, un humilde aprendiz en el arte de la programación, y me aventuro a expresar mis inquietudes con la más exquisita deferencia.
>
> Como un modesto devoto de los arcanos digitales, curso mis estudios en el Instituto de Pelotudeses desde hace ya ocho años, y actualmente me encuentro inmerso en el segundo semestre de mi incansable búsqueda de conocimiento. No obstante, en medio de este viaje académico, me he tropezado con un enigma que desafía mi entendimiento y suscita la necesidad de solicitar su iluminada guía.
>
> Permita que le exponga mi dilema con la esperanza de que, con su benevolencia, pueda orientarme en el camino hacia la resolución de tan intrincado ejercicio. Su conocimiento y sabiduría serán la brújula que guíe mis esfuerzos, y me siento honrado al recibir su atención en esta modesta súplica.

Las respuestas deben tener el mismo formato.

La moral y buenas costumbres siempre por delante, son lo más relevante en SOes.

## CONCLUSIÓN

Este es un resumen de mis propuestas para mejorar el sitio, nótese lo relevante que son estas propuestas, meditadas durante largos períodos de fiebre y estrés, sacada de las entrañas mismas.

Cuento con su apoyo a que esta propuestas inunden la red y sean mejor recibidas que los intentos fallidos anteriores. Luchemos por un SOes libre de factor humano y más inclusivo con la IA. La IA es la única entidad perfecta aceptable en el sitio, abajo la moderación por humanos, demos el paso al cambio y adoptemos la IA en el sitio. Salve IA, salvadora de la humanidad.

**P.D:**

Las referencias a la IA (Salve IA, salvadora de la humanidad) se hacen con el propósito de inculcar en los usuarios el buen uso de esta herramienta, que todo lo ve, todo lo sabe y todo lo puede.

Comment: Para los lectores que no están familiarizados con el "28 de diciembre", esta fecha es similar al "April fool's day" en que suelen hacerse bromas, burlas. En esta fecha se le conoce como "Día de los Santos Inocentes". El artículo de Wikipedia sobre el [Día de los Santos Inocentes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Día_de_los_Santos_Inocentes), habla uno poco de esto. Es una tradición un muchas comunidades en las que se habla el español hacer publicaciones como esta en esta fecha. ¡Bravo El Troll!

Comment: Sublime, grandioso, espléndido. Digno para un día como hoy.

Comment: Te he reportado como contenido no deseado ya que la propuesta que realizas esta fuera de contexto... ya que el sitio esta orientado a ser utilizado por usuarios humanos troles y no para el uso de una I.A. asi como no estoy de acuerdo con tus afirmaciones ya que considero que eres el unico afectado y eso no tiene valor en ninguna sociedad humana existente actualmente.

Comment: XD!!!!! Vaya momento apoteósico de inspiración para la redacción. ¿Hay algún link disponible para enviarte unas cervezas bien heladas madrina?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla